# Selecting at least three non consecutive integers from $\{x:x\le n; x,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The question requires me to find a general formula for selecting at least three non-consecutive integers within a range of natural numbers for any $n \in \{1,2,3,...\}$

**Added Restrictions:**
Any selection with both 1 and n is not a valid selection.

**MY ATTEMPT:**

I went about this question by trying to calculate the number of ways of selecting consecutive pairs and subtracting that from total possible selections, where total possible selections
$$T(n)= {n\choose 3}\cdot 2^{n-3}$$
The difficulty arose in calculating consecutive selections. I soon realised that accounting for all possible consecutive selections would be pretty difficult, and appears to be quite exhaustive.

Am I missing a crucial aspect in my approach, or is there a better method to approach this question?

Answer (score 1):

I will help you get started. For starters, ignore the "at least three" and "any set with both $1$ and $n$ is not valid" conditions.

The number of subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with no consecutive elements is $F_{n+2}$, where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers, defined by $F_1=F_2=1$ and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$. This can be proved by induction; letting $a_n$ be the number of nonconsecutive subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, then $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ as well, which can be seen by conditioning on whether $n$ is in the subset or not.

You then have to subtract out the nonconsecutive subsets with only zero, one or two elements, and subtract out the subsets containing both $1$ and $n$, being careful to add back in any doubly subtracted subsets. Once you have a formula, you can check it works by calculating the number of valid subsets by brute force for several small values of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a line of $n$ balls from which $3$ have been removed, so the line now consists of $(n-3)$ balls with $(n-3+1) = (n-2)$ uparrows where they can be inserted

$\uparrow \bullet\,\uparrow \bullet\,\uparrow \bullet\,\uparrow\bullet\, \uparrow \bullet\,\uparrow$

If you now re-number the balls after reinsertion, the count of the triplets  will be $\dbinom{n-2}3$, but you need to exclude combos where $1, n,$ and one number from $3\;\;thru\;\;(n-2)$  are disallowed

You should be able to complete the formula from here, selecting $4,5,...$ are non- consecutive.

Comment: "but you need to exclude combos where 1,n, and one number from 3 thru (n−2) are disallowed". I couldn't understand this part; do you mean to say we exclude combinations with over 3 balls?

Comment: @C_Lycoris:$1,n\,$ and$\, (3 \;thru\; n-2)$ exclusions are only   for triplets, there will be similar exclusions for others.